# Website Indexing in google search console dropped

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index

We are facing issues on google search console indexing page.

Issue 1: Due to some reason indexing dropped from 800 to 224 after website URL structure update

Issue 2: Wordpress xml sitemap missing few links when xml generated with yoast plugin

Due to site URL structure update some old link is crawling and new link is found in site xml, hopefully this issue will fix in some days once google keep updating links

Any solution and recommendation

[image]

Comment: If you're redirecting the old URLs to the new URLs using a `301` redirect, then it's really a matter of time (up to several weeks). You can [ask Google to recrawl your URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/ask-google-to-recrawl) too.

Answer (score 0):

You should resubmit website sitemap, then it will update.

Comment: Sitemap is probably of little value.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox